# Cannot generate thumbnail in Android Gallery

Tags: gallery, images, thumbnails

Lately, some of my pictures just disappear and can't be loaded. It just says "Cannot generate thumbnail". All of a sudden, those pictures are having 0KB and no longer available. They're not sorted or anything, they're not different from the other good pictures. I really don't get what's the problem.

I tried getting them on my laptop, but it just says the file is empty. There is nothing to open? There are no viruses or anything, I already checked a few times. I really don't want to lose more pictures. Please help.

Comment: Immediately back-up all pictures to your computer, because I think the SD card is failing. If it's internal memory, are the pictures instantly empty? Or are they empty after a while? Can you also state your make and model?

Answer (score -1):

Try Settings → Apps → All Apps → Gallery → Clear Data. That should regenerate thumbnails, or you could try rebooting your smartphone.